# Want to capture 'Enter' key press in HTML form field

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a HTML form text field( this is a form field),where I want to capture the whole text the end user put into that field along with the Enter key pressed for new lines.Like if i give an example, lets assume, I am putting the below string into the form text field exactly as it looks here:

```
I 
Pressed
Enter for a new Line.
```

Now, I want to save this filed input into the database exactly as end user filled it,for that My database string may looks like this

```
"I</br>Pressed</br>Enter for a new Line."
```

That is okey with me.But i don't want to store it like "I Pressed Enter for a new Line."

I have done it anyway.But there are many issues in my coding. Also, my requirement is it should be implemented in such a way, show that the same logic could be applied when the form will be open for editing and there will already be value in that text field from Database.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Watch out, hope it's a typo, `</br>` is not a valid tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `replace()` method for that,

```
$("textarea").val().replace(/\n/g, "<br />")
```

**Edit**

```
function captureEnter() {
 if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById("txtArea").value =document.getElementById("txtArea").value + "<br/>";
    return false;
}
else {
    return true;
}
}
```

***HTML***

```
<textarea id="txtArea" onkeypress="captureEnter();"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks Anoop for your reply. You have used regexp ,though not very much sure. But, my question is what if i don't do anything extra to catch an 'ENTER' hit in the text area(i mean i will only write into the text area and will hit ENTER to write into a new line), will your method take all ENTER hit into count?

Comment: @user3378974 is that what you want?

Comment: that exactly solved my issue. Thank you very much. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to capture when someone presses enter in a an `input` of `type=text`, and replace it with `<br/>`. If so, use the onkepress event, and listen for charcode 13, then add the "
" manually.

```
var tf = document.getElementById('myTextFIeld'); 
//or whatever method to find it you prefer.
tf.onkeypress = function(e) { 
  //or addEventListener('keypress',...) if you'd rather
  if (e.charCode === 13) {
    this.value += '<br/>'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it server side with **PHP** and *nl2br()*:

```
$thetext = nl2br($_GET['textarea']);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php